# Linux single binary for i386 and x86_64

Tags: linux, executable, 32bit-64bit

Suppose I have some code which compiles and works for both plain i386 and x86_64 arches.

In DOS/Windows one could bake a single MZ-PE executable, which could have one functionality in DOS and another in Windows. Or, in OSX there's possibility to combine i386 and PPC arches in single binary.

What about i386+x86_64 in Linux (without multiarch and such stuff)? Is it possible, and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use a shell script that extracted compressed copies of the application from later in the file. Supported sparc, x86 on Solaris. It's a relatively easy way of accomplishing it, but it relied on only using the relevant binaries for the relevant platform.

That said, it's much easier to have copies in a `bin-i386` and `bin-x86_64` directory and use `$(uname -m)` in a stub shell script to direct to the relevant binary e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash -p

exec ${0%/*}/bin-$(uname -m)/${0##*/} "$@"
```

If you're trying to ship 32bit binaries for a non multi-arch 64bit system, and because most applications will be compiled with dynamic linking then **libaries** are an additional problem. If you are not going to do multiarch, then you **have* * to ship all the relevant libraries (including the run-time linker `ld.so`), and use an `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to pick the appropriate libraries.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that I mist stated that so I changed the last paragraph. It actually represents a situation I've had to deal with in the past

Comment: Indeed it seems nothing better can be done on the ELF level.